# python beautifulsoup4 extract specefic data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi guys I want to extract some data like this I'm using python 3.6 and BeautifulSoup4 thanks for your help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = html_data = """
        <span class="some_data">
            title 1 : data 1
            <br/>
            title 2 : data 2
            <br/>
            title 3 : data 3
            <br/>
            <span class="meta_data">
                other additional data
            </span>
        </span>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

data = soup.find("span", class_="some_data").text

print(data)

# how to get only this : title 1 : data 1 / title 2 : data 2  / title 3 : data 3
# without  :    <span class="meta_data">
#                   other additional data
#               </span>
```

Comment: Cool... and I want to be the Master of the Universe. So what is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: @Andersson fine I have put the code

Comment: I'm not sure you can get desired output with BeautifulSoup, but you can get it with [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) and XPath `//span[@class="some_data"]/text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks I have solve my problem here is the code :

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

source = fromstring(source)

result = source.xpath("//span[@class='some_data']/text()")

for i in result :
    print(i.strip())
```